# Maximum call stack size exceeded at Array Iterator.next when filtering array for unique objects by id

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I need to filter an array and only get the unique objects with a unique ID.  I'm using and example I found online https://dev.to/vuevixens/removing-duplicates-in-an-array-of-objects-in-js-with-sets-3fep

I'm using the following code:

```js
allItin = [id: string, dateRange: [int], jobCode: string, act: [string], date: string, userId: string 
]

There are duplicate records in allItin as a result of the limitations of firebase queries.
this.filteredItineraries = Array.from(new Set(allItin.map(a => a.id)))
  .map(id => allItin.find(a => a.id === id));

console.log('unique', this.getUnique(this.filteredItineraries));
```

But I'm getting the Maximum call stack size in the console.  And in Visual Code when I hover over Set I get the following:

'Set only refers to a type but is being used as a value here'

and

'Cannot find name array'

One StackOverFlow post suggested changing to esg in my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Tried that to no avail.

Comment: This error message typically means that you have a cycle in your object definition. It's hard to say exactly what your cause is without seeing a standalone repro that we can run ourselves. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey this  will  occur  when some recursion is occurs can you  tell me what is sample input array and output then may be i can help you better to get the unique objects with a unique ID.

Comment: The input array is a collection of the following fields:
id: string
dateRange: [int]
jobCode: string
act: [string]
date: string
userId: string